# Not responsive. Changing between scenes JavaFX.

Tags: java, javafx, responsive-design, fxml, scene

I am trying to change my FXML files in one Stage, in borderPane>CENTER. It is working but the second FXML file is not responsive. Could someone help ?

Here are my files.

Main.java (only start method)

```
@Override
public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
    try {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml1.fxml"));

          Stage  stage = primaryStage;
            Scene scene = new Scene(root, 300, 275);

            stage.setTitle("FXML Welcome");
            stage.setScene(scene);
            stage.show();
    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

My controller.

```
public class fxmlTESTcontroller {

    @FXML
    private Button changeScene1;

    @FXML
    private VBox change;


    @FXML
    void changeSceneMethod(ActionEvent e) throws IOException
    {
        change.getChildren().clear();
        change.getChildren().add(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml2.fxml")));
    }
}
```

FXML 1

```
<AnchorPane xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="application.fxmlTESTcontroller">
   <children>
      <BorderPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="600.0" AnchorPane.bottomAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.leftAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.rightAnchor="0.0" AnchorPane.topAnchor="0.0">
         <left>
            <ListView maxWidth="200.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER" />
         </left>
         <center>
            <VBox fx:id="change" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
               <children>
                  <GridPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
                    <columnConstraints>
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                      <ColumnConstraints hgrow="SOMETIMES" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
                    </columnConstraints>
                    <rowConstraints>
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                      <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
                    </rowConstraints>
                     <children>
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text" />
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                        <TextField GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <TextArea prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
                        <Text strokeType="OUTSIDE" strokeWidth="0.0" text="Text" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
                     </children>
                  </GridPane>
                  <HBox>
                     <children>
                        <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                        <Button fx:id="changeScene1" mnemonicParsing="false" onAction="#changeSceneMethod" text="Button" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
                     </children>
                  </HBox>
               </children>
            </VBox>
         </center>
      </BorderPane>
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

and FXML 2

```
<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="100.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
   <children>
      <GridPane VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
        <columnConstraints>
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
          <ColumnConstraints hgrow="ALWAYS" minWidth="10.0" prefWidth="100.0" />
        </columnConstraints>
        <rowConstraints>
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="SOMETIMES" />
          <RowConstraints minHeight="10.0" prefHeight="30.0" vgrow="ALWAYS" />
        </rowConstraints>
         <children>
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Label" />
            <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Label" GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
            <Label text="Label" GridPane.rowIndex="2" />
            <TextArea GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.hgrow="ALWAYS" GridPane.rowIndex="2" GridPane.vgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </GridPane>
      <HBox VBox.vgrow="ALWAYS">
         <children>
            <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
            <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
         </children>
      </HBox>
   </children>
</VBox>
```

And here are the pictures of my [FXML1 (responsive)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ezbYQ.png) and [FXML2 (not responsive)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqUKe.png) after I run the app.

Could someone explain me why is that ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify which controller is responsible for handling actions on your `fxml` elements. In the first `fxml` sample, you have `fx:controller="application.fxmlTESTcontroller"`, which is basically saying that this controller class should take care of everything that is happening down on the `xml` tree under this element. You don't have such line in the second `fxml` so you have to specify which controller is responsible for the actions taken. Therefore you need a similar line in the second `fxml` file.

Moreover, you have to specify which method should take care of the action, when a button is pressed. Again, in the first file you have `onAction="#changeSceneMethod"`, which is saying that whenever the button is pressed, the `changeSceneMethod` should be invoked. However, you don't have such attribute in the second `fxml` and you need to add one, since nothing is currently listening for events on this button.

Comment: Yes, but I am trying to solve why when I load the fxml2 file its content is not responsive as it is in the fxml1.

Answer (score 0):

try

```
change.layout();
```

or

```
change.requestLayout();
```

after updating children list.